# App to make a call between iphone and android without internet

Tags: android, iphone-app

I ride my bicycle a lot and I have and android phone but my friend have an IPhone so I was asking can I call him without Internet like an app that opens a hotspot and he connect to it so we able to communicate with each other while both of us are riding bicycles.

Phone calls cost money (which is why we're looking for an alternative). We are not away in the range of the hotspot of a regular phone 2-4 meters when riding.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: how much are you willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? How far away from each other will you possibly be when attempting a call? And as for call w/o Internet: why do phone calls not fit?

Comment: Phone calls cost money, we are not away in the range of the hotspot of a regular phone 2-4 meters